# Pandas groupby feature question for output CSV

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following code

```
df.groupby('AccountNumber')[['TotalStake','TotalPayout']].sum()
```

which displays as I would like it to in pandas

The issue is when I output this to a CSV the first column AccountNumber disappears. How can I keep the AccountNumber column after using df.to_csv?

```
df = df.groupby('AccountNumber')[['TotalStake','TotalPayout']].sum()
df.to_csv("AccountNumbers.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Try `df.to_csv("AccountNumbers.csv", index=True)` .

Comment: That was it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.to_csv("AccountNumbers.csv", index=True)
```

was the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
df = df.groupby('AccountNumber')[['TotalStake','TotalPayout']].sum().reset_index()
df.to_csv("AccountNumbers.csv", index=False)
```